# Why do I have to clone the object before I can access to its property in a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, typeerror, clone

I fetched some data from the server, and tried to use in the react element, but i keep getting the type error of reading property from undefined.

```
import  React, { useEffect, useState }  from 'react';
import httpService from 'services/httpService';
function PageHighlight() {
  const [highlightItem,sethighlightItem]=useState({});
    async function fetchHighlightItem() {
        const {data}=await httpService.get('/PageHighlights');
        sethighlightItem(data)
    }
    useEffect(()=>{ fetchHighlightItem() },[]);
    console.log(highlightItem.NYCity)
    const item={...highlightItem["NYCity"]};
```

the result of `console.log(highlightItem.NYCity)` has already that it is a valid object:
[result of console.log show that is an object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18ZMo.png)

but when i tried to assign it to a variable and access it:`const item=highlightItem["NYCity"];` it return an type error of reading property from undefined.
[error ocurrs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCTiU.png)

if I cloned it to the variable:`const item={...highlightItem["NYCity"]};`, everything works, i can access to the property now. why? thank you.

Comment: The error is coming from somewhere down in your render. My guess is that `highlightItem["NYCity"]` is undefined on the initial render so when you `const item=highlightItem["NYCity"]` and try to access something like `item.foo` in the render, it throws error, but if you spread undefined into a defined object, `const item={...highlightItem["NYCity"]}`, now `item` is defined (`{}`) and `item.foo` simply returns undefined.

Comment: the weird thing is if I'm not trying to assign the that `highlightItem["NYCity"]` to a variable or try to access to the  `highlightItem["NYCity"]` object, everything is fine. i can even see the console.log(highlightItem["NYCity"]) shows that is an object successfully. it won't throw any error.

Comment: Are you sure you don't see a couple logs of the initial empty object (`{}`) state (well, undefined) before the fetch request completes and updates state?

Comment: oh, yes, it the log pannel did has two  empty object (`{}`) .  now i know it is because the `highlightItem` object is an empty object before the asyn/await function resolved. but what confuse me is when i use `console.log(highlightItem["NYCity"]);`,  it works, it doesn't need to the spread thing? why it can be used directly in console.log() function? thanks

Comment: Console logging is a bit *asynchronous*, in that you can log a currently empty object, and if the object is populated *before* the log buffer is outputted to the console you'll see a valid object even though in the rest of the code in a specific render cycle the object remains empty. This is why you shouldn't issue side-effects in the body of functional components, instead you should do any logging also in an effect hook which is guaranteed to be invoked once per render cycle.

Comment: Thank you. now I understand what went wrong.